# How to calculate previous fire time with apscheduler CronTrigger

Tags: python, apscheduler

Given a timezone aware datetime.datetime and an apscheduler CronTrigger, how can I calculate the fire_time of the trigger that was just before the datetime?

I have a function that works decently but failed for the specific example below.
I expected the datetime to be 2020-12-01 07:10:00+01:00 but I got 2020-11-01 07:10:00+01:00.

I'm using apscheduler 3.6.3.

```py
import datetime as dt
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

now = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 7, 10, 0, 123, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
trigger = CronTrigger(day=1, hour=7, minute=10)


def get_previous_fire_time(trigger, now):
    next_fire_time = trigger.get_next_fire_time(None, now)
    next_next_fire_time = trigger.get_next_fire_time(next_fire_time, next_fire_time)
    timedelta = next_next_fire_time - next_fire_time

    return trigger.get_next_fire_time(now - timedelta, now)


print(get_previous_fire_time(trigger, now))  # 2020-11-01 07:10:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm only works in one direction. To do it in the reverse direction, you need to look at the current code and modify it to work in the other direction. I'm not saying it won't be easy, but it should be possible if this is what you really want to do.